# Should the Box tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [box](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/box) tag has to do with an online service. Online services questions are better suited for [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), and typically end up off topic at Super User. The description is vague and the tag could be used inadvertently for other means.

Should the [box](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/box) tag be removed?

Comment: There are some questions about web services (i.e. interacting with them via CLI) that would still be on-topic. So maybe it should be renamed to `box.com` and the excerpt should state what's on topic and what is not. I wouldn't remove it.

Comment: @slhck Yes, but then you would have to create other tags for all the other `box` services, such as `drop-box`.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises We have a tag for Dropbox already?

Comment: @slhck I searched for it, and apparently no `dropbox`, or `drop-box` tag exists.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises Look again, under http://superuser.com/tags you will find [Dropbox](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dropbox)

Comment: @slhck Odd, it didn't come up when I searched for it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like someone already went ahead with it.